# How do you check if a c code is comiling with linux?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I submitted a C Code for an homework I had and for me and my friends. It seemed to be working with no warnings. We used VSCodium and a Terminal with an texteditor and a Debug Console, to both it seemed to be working just fine.

My teacher still said, that it didnt compile and that's why we got 0 points for it. I would like to ask if there are any other options to test if a code is working (a website, or to download something extra etc). I use the Linux system.

If someone has a tip I would really appreciate it. (If someone could check thess two codes for warnings/or if its compiling for me, would be nice)

the first is a calc.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
char operator;
double num1, num2;

printf("Geben sie einen Operator ein (+, -, *, /): ");
scanf("%c", &operator);

printf("Geben sie die beiden Zahlen nacheinander ein: ");
scanf("%lf %lf", &num1,&num2);

switch (operator)
{

case '+':
   printf("%.2lf + %.2lf = %.2lf",num1,num2,(num1+num2));
   break;

case '-':
   printf("%.2lf - %.2lf = %.2lf",num1,num2,(num1-num2));
   break;

case '*':
   printf("%.2lf * %.2lf = %.2lf",num1,num2,(num1*num2));
   break;

case '/':
    if( num2 != 0.0 )
        printf("%.2lf / %.2lf = %.2lf", num1,num2,(num1/num2));
    else 
        printf("durch 0 teilen geht nit");
    break;


default:
    printf("%c ist kein gültiger Operator",operator);
    break;
}

return 0;

}
```

and the second cat.c

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buf[80];
    char msg[50] = "hallo, hier steht immer was in foo steht";
    fd = open ("foo.txt", O_RDWR);
    printf("fd = %d", fd);
    if (fd != -1)
{
    printf("\n foo.txt wurde mit (sys)read und (sys)write geoffnet\n");
    write(fd, msg , sizeof(msg));
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, buf, sizeof(msg));
    printf("\n %s wurde in die datei geschrieben\n", buf);
    close (fd);
}

return 0;
}
```

this one should read what is written in foo.txt and other textdatas by calling it with e.g. "cat foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt"

Comment: Both compile with no warnings for me. I don't know what your teacher thinks the problem is.

Comment: This is what he said - not compiling? Or maybe not producing a correct output? If the former, ask him what his compiler is complaining about.

Comment: You need a better teacher, either one who knows how to compile programs or one who will explain exactly what error message they got that prevented them from compiling. Ask the teacher to do the latter. If they cannot, go to the person who is in charge of the teacher and explain the teacher is not administering the course work correctly.

Comment: You can try one of several online compilers: [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/), [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/), [godbolt.org](http://godbolt.org/), ..., ...

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the programs.

I think your professor is compiling with g++.
`operator` is a keyword in C++

I tried compiling with g++ and I got these warnings:

```
calc.c: In function ‘int main()’:
calc.c:4:14: error: expected type-specifier before ‘;’ token
    4 | char operator;
      |              ^
calc.c:8:22: error: expected type-specifier before ‘)’ token
    8 | scanf("%c", &operator);
      |                      ^
calc.c:13:17: error: expected type-specifier before ‘)’ token
   13 | switch (operator)
      |                 ^
calc.c:37:53: error: expected type-specifier before ‘)’ token
   37 |     printf("%c ist kein gültiger Operator",operator);
      |                                                     ^
make: *** [Makefile:7: calc] Error 1
```

Maybe provide your professor with a Makefile?

Comment: Alternately, resubmit the program with `operator` changed to something else, even `Operator`. If the teacher says it compiles then, this adds to the conjecture they compiled as C++ and that they have less than the desired amount of competence.

Comment: Or my preferred C++ gotcha!! `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error wrong (or mis-configured) compiler` / `#endif`